# Android Alpha Testing Google Play App

Tags: android, testing

I've uploaded apk file to G. Play and published it as alpha verion. Then I've add G group as testers and shared the link https://play.google.com/apps/testing/**** But there is nothing but a button "Become a tester" and no link to alpha version.

Where I can find a link?